# Angular 2 (typescript) Cast Json to Object[]

Tags: angular, typescript, casting

I have a server that have a route (/users for example) that return a list on user as json. I would like in my typeScript to convert the response json to an array of my user model.

For now i have something like this :

user.service.ts :

```
searchUser() : void {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/' + this.serializeUrlParam({}))
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(response => response.json() as User[])
                    .catch();
}
```

my user.ts :

```
export class User {
    infos: Object;
}
```

Where i use my service :

```
service.searchUser().then(userList=> {
        console.dir(userList)
});
```

When i display the return value of the `response.json()` i have this object :

```
{
    users: [
        { 
            Data : {
                ID : 1,
                Name : "foo",
                ....
            }
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

And when i'm displaying the final data (which should be and Array of User), I have the exact same object.

Is there a way to make the as operator create and instance of User for each entry of the 'users' array returned by `response.json()` and copy all the data (Id, name, etc) in the 'infos' field of the 'User' model ? By, like, override the as operator on my User model if it's possible ?

I would like to know if there is an other way that manually loop on each field, create an user instance push it to a 'result' array.

Thanks

Comment: In fact when you run the app. There are no User classes instances created. So if you want to have your data placed in some particular field or have those instances created you have to do it explicitly.

I would create this structure on the backend.

Comment: That's not the idea of types and interfaces in typescript. No, you cannot override the 'as' operator or any other operator. I would change to ```.then(response => response.json().users as User[])``` and change the User class to an interface that has ```Data: {Id: number; Name: string}```.

Comment: You'd have to do something like `response.json().users.map(rawUser => createUserFrom(rawUata))`

Comment: Thanks all, @jonrsharpe this is exactly the type of behavior that i would like. Is this considered as "good typescript oriented" approach ? or it's a "better not to do it" ?

Comment: With so little information it's hard to tell. The `User` class currently seems completely pointless: 1. if you don't have any *behaviour* to go with the data you could just use an `interface` (in which case you probably wouldn't need an explicit conversion); and 2. `infos: Object` gives little useful information about what to expect when you're trying to *consume* a user.

Comment: hum ok i see, in fact i'm more used to c / c++ / c# where creating class to be used as model is usual. Mainly my User class will be used to store Data about user. I'm not really familiar right now with Typescript project architecture, i followed some docs that used this kind of class to store data about user or .... Because i'm used to that i made the same. but maybe it's not the good approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with comments, you could very well use an Interface, and in fact I would very likely do it myself, even though the Angular style guide suggests to use classes: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces

Here is a solution for your class (without constructor). What I'd do is to actually want to get rid of the `Data` property from your response and end up with a class like this:

```
export class User {
  ID: number;
  Name: string;
  ....
}
```

Here's how to make the objects of the above class, where we first map the array and then we create instance of the `User` class from the `Data` object:

```
searchUser() : void {
  return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/' + this.serializeUrlParam({}))
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json().users.map(user =>
        Object.assign(new User(), user.Data)))
    .catch();
}
```

Now we end up with an array with instances of the above `User` class.