# How to map HTTP response to user defined type?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

```ts
// interface    
export interface IMovie {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    releaseDate: string;
    genre: string;
}

//component:

movie: IMovie = null;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      const movie_id = parseInt(params.get('movie_id'), 10);
      this.movieService.getMovieById(movie_id)
        .subscribe((movie) => this.movie = movie);
    });
  }

//service
getMovieById(movie_id: number): Observable<IMovie> {
    return this.http.get<IMovie>(url);
}
```

When I am trying to print in the component code I am able to see the Object (`console.log(movie)`), I don't understand why the mapping i.e Object -> `IMovie` is not happening.

I tried in different ways nothing worked for me.

Comment: Type hints **do not cause any casting or conversion**. Given that all of the value types in `IMovie` are primitive, what would you even want to be converted? Interfaces don't even *exist* at runtime, you're always just going to see a plain object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No methods in http response object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102824/no-methods-in-http-response-object)

Comment: I want to use the "movie" object in the template, but the response movie object is not assigned to this.movie object. I tried to print this.movie which is showing null.

Comment: What jonrsharpe is trying to tell you is that `<IMovie>` has no effect on the code at runtime, it's just here to help you code and debug when you are using your IDE.

Comment: *Where* did you try to `console.log(this.movie)`. Until the callback to the inner subscription gets invoked that will still be the original value, which *you set to `null`*. You have to wait for the `params` subscription to provide the parameter value, *then* for the HTTP request to complete, before you'll have a non-`null` value. And none of that is anything to do with whether or not the response is being mapped to an interface.

Comment: `
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      const movie_id = parseInt(params.get('movie_id'), 10);
      this.movieService.getMovieById(movie_id)
        .subscribe((movie) => this.movie = movie);
    });
console.log(this.movie);
  }
`

Comment: Thats wrong. log in inside subscribe

Comment: 1. [Edit] the question, code is unreadable in comments. 2. It's guaranteed to still be `null` there, the whole point of using observables and callbacks is that you have two *asynchronous* operations happening before that value gets set. I'd strongly encourage reading up on these topics, they're crucial to using Angular.

Comment: Analogy: you're trying to eat a toast immediately after you put it inside the toaster. The tost is not ready at that time. It's only ready when the toaster notifies you that the toast is grilled, i.e. when the callback passed to subscribe() is called. That's what asynchronism is.

Comment: @JBNizet nice. The analogy could use a toasting fork instead of a toaster, but that would be anachronistic asynchrony.