# TypeScript myFunction is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, function

I am working in Angular and I have a following situation:

**my.service.ts** has this class:

```
export class MyClass {
    MyList: string[] = [];
    MyString: string = '';

    createString(): void {
        this.MyList.forEach(s => {
            this.MyString += s + ', ';
        });
    }
}
```

And **my.component.ts** calls it like this:

```
myData: MyClass[] = [];

this.myService.getMyData().subscribe(res => {
    myData = res;
    if (myData.length > 0) {
        this.myData.forEach(x => x.createString());
    }
});
```

VS Code recognizes the `createString` function as a metod of `MyClass`, but I still get an error:

> ERROR TypeError: x.createString is not a function

Any explanations?

*EDIT*: The data comes from back end, and the back end model doesn't have this method. Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: If you are transfering using JSON, you are only transfering data, not methods or classes. You need to have code that will reify JSON as your class. Without it... TS believes `x` should be a `MyClass`, so VSCode lets you do completion; but `x` is in actuality probably just a POJO.

Comment: The issue would be that the response you get is not your class objects, they are normal Javascript objects, create instances first

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25401

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No methods in http response object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102824/no-methods-in-http-response-object)

Comment: @jonrsharpe reading this question and answers I realize that, yes, it is the same problem.

Comment: Also note that checking `myData.length > 0` is pointless - if it's an empty array it'll just loop over zero things, and if it's not an array the check will likely fail to find a length property.

Comment: @jonrsharpe seeing all this, I think I'll build that string on the server side. That way, I'll have to check nothing at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's not just the `length` check - there is a lot of unnecessary code. The `forEach` in `createString` can just be replaced with `this.MyList.join(", ")` and the `forEach` for calling `createString` also strikes me as unnecessary - the `string` property could just have a dynamic getter that builds the the value on demand and caches it, instead of having to call an extra method to populate it on each element and each time the observable pushes an update.

Comment: @VLAZ well, I was trying to piece together a rough illustration of the problem, not optimize the code. If you comment on every single line, you'd have to say that naming is a bit fishy, right? :) The final code is significantly different, but that was not the point of this question. Nevertheless, you are completely right about unnecessary code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object coming from the server will be just a simple object not an instance of the class `MyClass`. You can create instances of `MyClass` and assign the values from the server object  to the instance of the class:

```
this.myService.getMyData().subscribe(res => {
    myData = res.map(o => Object.assign(new MyClass(), o));
    if (myData.length > 0) {
        this.myData.forEach(x => x.createString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted soulution didn't help me, so I propose mine. It does not require `.map()`.

**My http service:**

```
getOffers() {
    return this.http.get('https://ohipo.pl/assets/oferty.json');
  }
```

**Consuming service in component:**

```
offers: Offer[] = [];

this.offersService.getOffers().subscribe((response: Offer[]) => {

      for (let i in response) {
        this.offers[i] = Object.assign(new Offer(), response[i]);
      }
```

Comment: Besides the fact that using `map` is cleaner than a for loop, it's basically the same answer as the accepted one. If you encountered another issue you should explain what it was and how your version solves this issue.