# Angular 8: myMethod is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 8 application with the following code:

```
export class ResponseModel<T> {
   status: string;
   message: string;
   data: T;

   isSuccess(): boolean {
      return '00' === status;
   }

}
```

and the following...

```
this.httpClient.get(myUrl)
  .subscribe((response: ResponseModel<any>) => {

    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        // Rest of the code
    }
}
```

The `response: ResponseModel` object serializes well from the `http` result but `response.isSuccess()` throws an error:

```
TypeError: response.isSuccess() is not a function
```

What could be wrong with my code above?

Comment: What is new’ing the response object? Nothing I am betting.

Comment: The solution is probably given by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103129/1009922).

Comment: @RamblinRose, I thought defining the type of response creates an object from the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By declaring `response: ResponseModel<any>`, you are telling the Typescript compiler that you expect `response` to be of the type `ResponseModel<any>`, or at least conform to its interface. Declaring the type doesn't automatically make it an instance of that type.

`ResponseModel<T>` is a class that you have created - the http client knows nothing about it.

`response` is some object. You need to create an instance of `ResponseModel<T>` from `response` if you want an instance of it.

```js
this.httpClient.get(myUrl).pipe(
  map((response: any): ResponseModel<any> => {
    const response = new ResponseModel<any>();
    // TODO: set the properties
    response.status = response.status;
    return response;
  })
).subscribe((response: ResponseModel<any>) => {
    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        // Rest of the code
    }
}
```

Comment: This one worked. Though, to avoid setting all properties one by one, one can use `const rsp = Object.assign(new ResponseModel<any>(), response);`

Comment: Correct. The crux of your problem was not creating an instance of the class - I didn't want to get bogged down in the various ways you can set the properties. Personally, I prefer to keep control over what properties I'm setting. `Object.assign` will copy all properties across, regardless of whether or not they're declared on the class.